# How set VGA use only NVIDIA in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gpu

As I check my GPU info by using this command :

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
```

It said that I have only one choice and that was my **Integrated Graphics** card.

> VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor
> Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
> Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
> Kernel driver in use: i915

[image]

But I have one NVIDIA GPU too which `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` didnt show it.
I installed its driver and by using `sudo prime-select nvidia`  I use it.

[image]

this is its info:

[image]

My problem and question is that how can I disable intel Integrated Graphics card and use only NVIDIA.

I want to see NVIDIA GeForce 840M  as I run `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` command.

**update:**

I check my BIOS setting and my Display was set to NVIDIA

[image]

So I think this should be disable intel GPU but **nothing changed** it still works. My system is lenevo thinkpad E440.

This is my Device and I/O Ports there is no Internal Graphics option:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS to see if there is a setting to disable the onboard / on-chip video.

Comment: @Terrance thanks for your comment I update my question and I checked BIOS but it already set NVIDIA in Display settings I didnt find other way to disable intel GPU.

Comment: Is there this setting in the BIOS?  System setting -> Device and I/O Ports -> Internal Graphics.  Was just looking at Lenovo support page for systems and wondering if you BIOS has that.  Unfortunately, I don't own one nor have I ever used one so this is all I can find.  https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht114073-disable-integrated-graphics-device-igd-when-using-intel-core-i3-processor-or-intel-pentium-processor-ibm-system-x3250-5458

Comment: One other idea I just had was to try using `sudo prime-select nvidia` then reboot to see if maybe that might help push your system to at least have the NVIDIA chipset as the primary.

Comment: @Terrance You have mentioned an important point which is exactly my problem
I ran the command `sudo prime-select nvidia`  and it shows nvidia is enabled as I run `prime-select query` but  Integrated Graphics  still was set for VGA and `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` should tell me NVIDIA too but it didnt and it only could find intel. AlsoI update my question and add pictures there is no Internal Graphics option in  I/O Ports.